# How to reconfigure the mirror in Sculpt Mode?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, mirror, mirror-modifier

I am trying to model to a fish skull or neurocranium. Below is the screenshot of what I am encountering when I try to sculpt mirror along the X, Y, and Z axes. It is not sculpting uniformly on both sides on one axis, nor the left dot does not align with my cursor. This is the first time I encountered this since previous fish skull models uniformly modeled correctly. [image: Screenshot of the mirror on Y axis]

Comment: maybe apply the rotation of your object and symmetrize?

Comment: The mirror uses the origin of the model (orange dot in *Object* mode) as the center. Looks like the model's origin is at the world's origin (at least for Y) but the geometry is moved in the positive Y direction. Go to *Object* mode and use menu *Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* to reset the origin.